# VirtualBox with a transparent drive

Tags: virtualbox

I want to create a virtualbox VM for experimenting with Linux that uses a directory or some device that is completely transparent to the outside. Further, I do not want networking to work on this VM.

Essentially I want it to look very much like a chroot system, but it should be running in it's own emulated environment.

Either that or I want the vdi or some other kind of emulation of a hardware I use to be mountable read/write on the host system.

Answer (score 0):

[Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/) machines share a directory, `/vagrant`, between host and guest. The entire filesystem isn't shared but anything in that directory is. It's the root of your vagrant project on the host machine and `/vagrant` on the guest.